# Open user's library folder using Applescript

Tags: applescript

I would like to open a folder that defaults to an application's settings folder:

```
/Users/XXX/Library/Application Support/Tunnelblick/Configurations
```

I don't want to 'hard code' the 'XXX'.

The `/library` folder:

```
set theDestination to (choose folder with prompt "Open destination folder" default location (path to library folder))
```

The `home` folder:

```
set theDestination to (choose folder with prompt "Open destination folder" default location (path to home folder))
```

I'm not sure how to get the `~/Library` folder and one of its subfolders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paths to the librarys are:

```
POSIX path of (path to library folder from user domain)
```

= ~/Library/

```
POSIX path of (path to library folder from local domain)
```

= /Library/

```
POSIX path of (path to library folder from system domain)
```

= /System/Library/

Comment: `user domain` = `~/Library`.  What's the difference between `local domain` and `system domain`?

Answer (score 2):

The system also knows about the application support folder:

```
set aFolderPath to ((path to application support folder from user domain) as text) & "Tunnelblick:Configurations:"
try
    set destinationPath to aFolderPath as alias
on error
    beep
    log aFolderPath & " missing"
    return
end try
set theDestination to (choose folder with prompt "Open destination folder" default location destinationPath)
```

See `StandardAdditions`, `path to`

```
path to v : Return the full path to the specified folder
path to application support/applications folder/desktop/desktop pictures folder/documents folder/downloads folder/favorites folder/Folder Action scripts/fonts/help/home folder/internet plugins/keychain folder/library folder/modem scripts/movies folder/music folder/pictures folder/preferences/printer descriptions/public folder/scripting additions folder/scripts folder/services folder/shared documents/shared libraries/sites folder/startup disk/startup items/system folder/system preferences/temporary items/trash/users folder/utilities folder/workflows folder/voices/apple menu/control panels/control strip modules/extensions/launcher items folder/printer drivers/printmonitor/shutdown folder/speakable items/stationery : the folder to return
[from system domain/local domain/network domain/user domain/Classic domain] : where to look for the indicated folder
[as type class] : the type to return: alias or string (default is alias)
[folder creation boolean] : Create the folder if it doesn’t exist? (default is true)
→ alias : the path to the specified folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
set theDefault to (path to home folder as text) & "Library:Application Support:Tunnelblick:Configurations" as alias

set theDestination to (choose folder with prompt "Open destination folder" default location theDefault)
```